# Error: ArrayBoundsError when using variable

Tags: arrays, d

I have a static size array of length 1, which I try to assign a value at index 0.

```
void main() {
   int length = 0;
   int[1] arr;

   arr[0] = 1;
   arr[length] = 2;
}
```

With the above code, I get a runtime error of

```
Error: ArrayBoundsError array.d(6)
```

which cooresponds the line: arr[length] = 2.

Why does the constant 0 work, but the variable with value 0 not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`length` has a special meaning inside index/slice expressions - it does the same thing as `$` (the length of the array being indexed/sliced). Thus, `arr[length]` will always result in an `ArrayBoundsError`.

Note: `length` is deprecated in D2, and both D1 and D2 will issue a warning (when warnings are enabled): `array 'length' hides other 'length' name in outer scope`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added `alais gdc='gdc -Wall'` to my .bashrc to help find these types of problems with warnings.

Comment: Ironically, this exact bug is the source of the name for my blog.

Comment: @BCS: I'll bite... what's the name of your blog?

Comment: Ok, I wasn't going to list it because it's in my profile but, URL: http://arrayboundserror.blogspot.com/ name: `return Array[$];`